# Каким образом запросить все измененные элементы формы?

Tags: javascript, java, html, html5, jsp

На форме есть множество элементов, которые формируются динамическим образом.

```
<table class="table">

    <c:forEach var="row" items="${rs0.rows}">
        <c:set var="SIGNIFICATIVE" value="${row.SIGNIFICATIVE}"/>
        <c:set var="ID_SIGNIFICATIVE" value="${row.ID_SIGNIFICATIVE}"/>
        <tr>
            <td>  <input type="checkbox" id="${ID_SIGNIFICATIVE}" NAME="CHECKBOX_${ID_SIGNIFICATIVE}"></td> <td style="width:50%">${SIGNIFICATIVE}</td>
            <td><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="${ID_SIGNIFICATIVE}" NAME="TEXT_${ID_SIGNIFICATIVE}" > <span class="input-group-addon">,%</span> </div></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>
```

Далее информацию из этих элементов формы необходимо занести в БД.
Подскажите метод, которым возможно получить список измененных элементов формы.

Comment: Зависит от того, где именно нужно проверять изменения. Если на клиенте — навешивайте события на onChange. Если на сервере — запрашивайте из бд оригинал и сравнивайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получилось сделать таким образом,
здесь запрашивается состояние всех объектов формы,
плюс отфильтровываются объекты формы типа
['checkbox', 'radio', 'button', 'submit'].
и в vars_for_update добавляются только те, по которым было изменение

```js
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
   function GetValue () {
        var result = [];
        var vars_for_update="";
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelector('form').elements, function (el) {
            if (['checkbox', 'radio', 'button', 'submit'].indexOf(el.type) === -1 ) // || el.checked
            {
                //var elem = el.name;
                var defValue = el.defaultValue;
                var currvalue = el.value;
                var index = el.selectedIndex;
                if (index) defValue = el.options[0].value;
                if (defValue == currvalue || index === 0) {
                    result.push(el.name + ' :: ' + el.value+' :: '+" Значение не изменилось");
                } else {
                    result.push(el.name + ' :: ' + el.value+' :: '+" Значение изменилось с " + defValue +
                            "\n  на " + currvalue);
                    vars_for_update=vars_for_update+el.name + '==' + el.value+"<>;";
                }
            }
        });
        demo.innerHTML = result.join('<br>');
        if (vars_for_update!="") {
            document.getElementById("Text_Update").value=vars_for_update;              
        }
    }
</SCRIPT>
```